# TABLEAU Sheet Swap with Action Filter

Tags: tableau-api

Hope you can help me solve this finally, I`m trying to create a sheet swap with action filters, that means that if you click on something on the graph another graph appears: For example

[image]

If someone could give me the steps to achieve it I`ll be happy to hear, 10x!

Comment: Based on this graphic, you want Technology to show one graph but Office Supplies to show a different worksheet. In other words, the bottom viz type should be dynamic based on the dimension's value clicked above? If so, what criteria determines the viz type?

Comment: Exactly what you said, the criteria can be the use of different images on top, clicking on each image will show a different worksheet at the bottom